# PHP/Mysql: optimize query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following script that retrieve numbers from 2 tables, make a sum, and the value is updated into a 3th table.

```
$query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(net_amount) FROM fin_costos WHERE month='1' AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='2014' ) + 
(SELECT SUM(net_amount) FROM em2_fin_costs WHERE month='1' AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='2014') AS total";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){$valor_final = $row['total']; }

$query_update="UPDATE fusion_analysis SET jan='$valor_final' WHERE year_for_analysis='2014' AND item_for_analysis='general' AND category='general'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_update);
```

I need to run the same script for each month of the year. Everything is exaclty the same except the variable 'month' that changes from 1 to 12 and the SET in UPDATE where the value is uploaded for each month ('jan','feb', 'mar'...etc)

I'm currently just copying and pasting the same script changing this few parameters but I believe there is a smarter way to do this in less lines of code I have

Answer (score 0):

See date function of PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(net_amount)"
    . " FROM fin_costos"
    . " WHERE month='".date('n')."'"
    ." AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='".date("Y")."' ) +"
    ."(SELECT SUM(net_amount) FROM em2_fin_costs WHERE month='".date('n')."'"
    . " AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='".date("Y")."') AS total";

$query_update="UPDATE fusion_analysis"
    . " SET `".  strtolower(date('M'))."`='$valor_final'"
    . " WHERE year_for_analysis='".date("Y")."'"
    . " AND item_for_analysis='general'"
    . " AND category='general'";
```

**NOTE:**

`Y` - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits like 2014

`n` - Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros 1 - 12

`M` - A short textual representation of a month, three letters Jan through Dec

For month as short textual I've used the `strtolower` function to make it lowercase.

UPDATE

Based on OP comment:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(net_amount)"
        . " FROM fin_costos"
        . " WHERE month='" . $i . "'"
        . " AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='" . date("Y") . "' ) +"
        . "(SELECT SUM(net_amount) FROM em2_fin_costs WHERE month='" . $i . "'"
        . " AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='" . date("Y") . "') AS total";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $valor_final = $row['total'];

    $monthName = strtolower(date('M', strtotime(date("Y") . "-" . str_pad($month,2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-" . date("01") )));

    $query_update = "UPDATE fusion_analysis"
        . " SET `" . $monthName . "`=' " . $valor_final . "'"
        . " WHERE year_for_analysis='" . date("Y") . "'"
        . " AND item_for_analysis='general'"
        . " AND category='general'";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_update);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For what I see this will run the update only for the current month. What happens if the date is -for example- August, but the user changes a cost from January. Then this cost will not be updated.

Comment: Then you need to create a form on a page, where user can set the date. But you've wrote this: `I need to run the same script for each month of the year. `

Comment: exactly, but the thing is that the script should be run for the 12 months at the same time, no matter the date of the use.

Comment: Is this mean, you want to run the update query for 1-12 month, in every month with the same `$valor_final`, or you want to select the 1-12 and update 1-12? Not really understand.

Comment: I want to run the query and update the 12 months in one go. $valor_final changes based on the variable 'months'. The page will display the values for all the year. I hope it explains a bit more clear.

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't try it yet but at first sight seems to do the job. The only one line I dont get how is done is this one: 

 $monthName = strtolower(date('M', strtotime(date("Y") . "-" . str_pad($month,2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-" . date("01") )));